# Returning json_encode as array not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Here is my button

```
$( "#editVehicle" ).button().click(function( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var vp = $("input[name=vehicle_plate]").val(),
    dataString = 'vehicle_plate='+ vp;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "editvehicle.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            if(!data.error && data.success) {
                $("input[name=vehicle_model]").val(data.vehicleName);
                $("input[name=assigned_driver]").val(data.assignedDriver);
            } else {
                alert(data.errorMsg);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

And here is my PHP

```
<?PHP
include("db.classes.php");
$g = new DB();
$g->connection();

if($_POST) {
    $vehiclePlate = $g->clean($_POST["vehicle_plate"],1);
    $g->edit($vehiclePlate);
}
$g->close();
?>
```

and here is my db.classes

```
public function edit($vehiclePlate)
{
    $sql = "select vehicle_name, driver_id from vehicles where vehicle_plate='$vehiclePlate'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(json_encode(array("error" => 0, "errorMsg" => "MySQL query failed.")));
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if(mysql_num_rows($row)) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "success" => 1,
            "vehicleName" => $row['vehicle_name'],
            "assignedDriver" => $row['driver_id']
        ));
    } 
    else {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "error" => 1,
            "errorMsg" => "No rows returned"
        ));
    }

}
```

button tag

```
<button type="submit" id="editVehicle" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-text">Edit</span>
</button>
```

There is an input field in my html where i input the vehicle plate then when the user clicks the button the program searches the database for the vehicle name and driver_id with the plate the user entered and returns the value to another inputfield named **"vehicle_name"** and **"assigned_driver"** but nothing is happening when the button is clicked not even the error alert message. Any idea on where am i going wrong here?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong.. From what you're saying it's a problem with the javascript and not the php? Can you confirm `#editVehicle` exists before the javascript to bind the event fires? Is the javascript inside of a `$(document).ready(function(){`? Can you confirm that the ajax call is firing?

Comment: See my edit for editVehicle button.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here -

```
if(!data.error && data.success) {
```

You are returning only either `succcess` or `error` but not both simultaneously, so the condition is always false.

Either return both or check of undefined property `error` and `success` before the condition like -

```
if ((typeof data.error != 'undefined' && !data.error) || (typeof data.success != 'undefined' && data.success))
```

And since you are returning `error` separately then you don't need to check with if, you can also try this and probably the better solution-

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "editvehicle.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){

        $("input[name=vehicle_model]").val(data.vehicleName);
        $("input[name=assigned_driver]").val(data.assignedDriver);

    },
    error: function(data){
        alert(data.errorMsg);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: the 2nd sulotion returns undefined while the first nothing happens

Comment: are you using firebug console?.. can you send me the response?

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ use this plugin and check what is the response from server. You will be able to see direct response of server and thus will be able to find the reason why it is showing undefined.

Comment: Chrome has different set of developer tools, in chrome use - Tools > Developer Tools... after opening the tools (network tab in the tools section), click on the edit button and you will be able to see the ajax call log and also the request and response

Comment: it says there is an error here  "if(mysql_num_rows($row)).. on my db.classes

Comment: Additional: Warning: Mysql_num_rows() Expects Parameter 1 To Be Resource array given -this is the error